# Accept x-www-form-urlencoded in Web API .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API that is returning a 415 Unsupported Media Error when I try to post some data to it that includes some json.  Here's part of what is returned in the Chrome Debugger:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:51608/api/trackAllInOne/set
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Accept:text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action:finish
currentSco:CSharp-SSLA:__How_It_Works_SCO
data:{"status":"incomplete","score":""}
activityId:13
studentId:1
timestamp:1519864867900
```

I think this has to do with my controller not accepting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data - but I'm not sure.  I've tried decorating my controler with `Consumes` but that does not seem to work.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/trackAllInOne/set")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] PlayerPackage playerPackage)
{ etc..}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

The following code worked fine in .NET 4.6.1 and I am able to capture and process the posts shown above.

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(PlayerPackage))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLearningRecord(PlayerPackage playerPackage)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var id = Convert.ToInt32(playerPackage.ActivityId);
    var learningRecord = await _context.LearningRecords.FindAsync(id);
    if (learningRecord == null)
        return NotFound();
etc...
```

Comment: What is `PlayerPackage `? How did you send the request from Front?

Comment: PlayerPackage is information sent from an online course tracking a student's progress in that course.  I have no control over how the system makes it posts.  The job of my WebApi is t capture these posts and save them in my tracking system.

Comment: Do you want to accept data with `data:{"status":"incomplete","score":""}` or you want to log all the body `action:finish
currentSco:CSharp-SSLA:__How_It_Works_SCO
data:{"status":"incomplete","score":""}
activityId:13
studentId:1
timestamp:1519864867900`

Comment: Yes, I do want to accept the json data;{"status: "incomplete" etc..  That's the critical part and is what is stopping it from working.  When I remove the json, it seems to work fine - but the json is what I need the most.

Comment: The following code used to work fine in .net 4.6.1 for the same posts: 
    `[ResponseType(typeof(PlayerPackage))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> 
    PostLearningRecord(PlayerPackage playerPackage)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var id = Convert.ToInt32(playerPackage.ActivityId);
            var learningRecord = await _context.LearningRecords.FindAsync(id);
            if (learningRecord == null)
                return NotFound();`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For `PlayerPackage`, the request should send a **PlayerPackage Json Object**, based on your description, you could not control the request which is posted from other place.

For the request, its type is  **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**， it will send data with **{"status":"incomplete","score":""}** in string Format instead of Json object. If you want to accept **{"status":"incomplete","score":""}**, I suggest you change the method like below, and then convert the string to Object by `Newtonsoft.Json`

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/trackAllInOne/set")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] string data)
{
    PlayerPackage playerPackage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerPackage>(data);
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: I have followed this, but my "data" is null when sending from postman. Any idea why?

Comment: @r3plica, I would use a custom type instead of string.  Put data in a type itself, then next to the [FromForm], put [FromForm] CustomType request, and then in that custom type, access the data property (or other properties that are part of the form encoded request).  That's what I did my case, and it works.

Comment: @firecape I am having the exact same issue, the data comes null and the former value is an string.

Answer (score 88):

Try using `[FromForm]` instead of `[FromBody]`.

```cs
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] PlayerPackage playerPackage)
```

- `FromBody` > Bind from JSON
- `FromForm` > Bind from Form parameters

You can also remove `[FromBody]` altogether and trial it then. Because you are expecting form-urlencoded should tell it to bind to object.

Comment: Ok, another thing that you can try is remove it altogether (not ideal but it works).

Comment: Anyway we can make it work for both application/x-www-urlencoded and application/json? I'm creating two functions with same route name, and sharing a private function to make this work, but I'd wonder if there is easier way to support both JSON and FORM binding.

Comment: Robin, woud it work to have method 2 signatures.  One with a [Consumes] attribute for url forms and another with application/json?  Then one has [FromFrom] and the other [FromBody].  Get one method to call the other directly once it has bound.  Just a thought.  not tested.  I thought if you removed the [From...] attribute it would figure it out but maybe they need the [consumes] attribute to help?

Comment: AWESOME! `[FromForm]` that was my fault too

Answer (score 34):

This did the trick for me:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]IFormCollection value)
```

Comment: `IFormCollection` is key. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can make setting like as

```cs
[HttpPost()]/[HttpGet()]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public async Task<IActionResult>  MethodName([FromForm] IFormCollection value)
```

don't forget to add **[FromForm]**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. FormDataCollection has no default constructors which is required by Formatters. Use IFormCollection instead.

Comment: Use [FromForm] attribute instead of [FromBody]

Comment: public IActionResult Search([FromForm]IFormCollection type)
        {
            return Ok();
        }