# MVC can not get JSON from request Post "x-form-urlencoded"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm try to get JSON from body but I always get  null.

This is my code in MVC

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class NimsoftController : Controller
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<Guid, Alert> alerts = new Dictionary<Guid, Alert>();

        // GET: Nimsoft
        //public ActionResult CreateAlarm()
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage CreateAlarm([FromBody] Alert val)
        {
            Models.CreateAlarm CreateAlarm = new Models.CreateAlarm();
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\log.txt", string.Join(",", val.message));
            string jsonAlarm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
               message = "Test Message"//string.Join(",",alert.alerts),
            });

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonAlarm)
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

and my request

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:52151
Content-Length: 27 '
```

Comment: Can you add the complete request with form content? Maybe this 
 will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49042444/5031787

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `mediaType` parameter of `StringContent` to `application/json`:

```
Content = new StringContent(jsonAlarm, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```