# Can`t recive POST request Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: curl, asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate

Can`t recive 3ds party POST request. 415 Unsupported Media type or empty model

On backend: Asp.net core 2.2 and Aspnetbilerplate(if its important)

request from a third-party server, so I can not influence it. I can only specify the endpoint to which requests will be sent

Looks like that:
curl http://MyServer/api/MyController/MyAction -d '{"a":"a", "b":1}'

My code
Dto:

```
    public class testDto
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : MyControllerBase
{
   ...
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<testDto> MyAction(testDto dto)
   {
     //some code
     _logger.Info("test");            
   }
   ...
}
```

My test request from console with results:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -d '{"a":"a", "b":1}' http://myServerUrl/api/MyController/MyAction
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 4
{"result":{"a":null,"b":0},"targetUrl":null,"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}
```

Model is empty, no binding has occurred.

I am added [FromBody] to action like that:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<testDto> MyAction([FromBody]testDto dto)
   {
     //some code
     _logger.Info("test");            
   }
```

Result: HTTP status code 415

Also, try adding [FromForm] and [FromQyesry]. Result: empty model

What is the problem? How do I make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `curl -d` posts content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. Does the 3rd party sends such requests or is your `curl` setup mistaken?

Comment: the third party sends me curl exactly in this form. I can only adapt somehow =(

Comment: In that case, the content-type and data don't match; have a look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041127/accept-x-www-form-urlencoded-in-web-api-net-core

Comment: unfortunately did not work in my case =( string parameter is still null

 [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public async Task<testDto> MyAction([FromForm] string data)
        {            
            var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testDto>(data);
            return dto;
        }

Comment: also tried [FromBody] - error 415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is the request `curl http://MyServer/api/MyController/MyAction -d '{"a":"a", "b":1}'` is not correct , you could see the protocol use :

```
curl http://MyServer/api/MyController/MyAction -d '{"a":"a", "b":1}' --trace-ascii debugdump.txt
```

If checking the dump file , you will find the data is not completely sent :

```
0000: POST /api/values/MyAction HTTP/1.1
0024: Host: localhost:44348
003b: User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
0054: Accept: */*
0061: Content-Length: 6
0074: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00a5: 
=> Send data, 6 bytes (0x6)
0000: '{a:a,
== Info: upload completely sent off: 6 out of 6 bytes
== Info: schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
== Info: schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
== Info: schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
== Info: schannel: encrypted data got 322
== Info: schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 322 length 103424
```

You should contact with 3ds party to confirm the request .

Anyway , if default model binding doesn't meet your requirement , you can create [Custom Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

1. Adding middleware to make request `EnableRewind` :

   ```
   app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
   {
       ctx.Request.EnableRewind();
       await next();
   });
   ```
2. Create custom binder which implements `IModelBinder`:

   ```
   public class testDtoEntityBinder : IModelBinder
   {
       public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           if (bindingContext == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
           }


           var body = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
           body.Position = 0;


           string raw = new System.IO.StreamReader(body).ReadToEnd();

           //now read content from request content and fill your model 
           var result = new testDto
           {
               A = "",
               B = 1,
           };


           bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
   ```
3. User the binder :

   ```
   [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(testDtoEntityBinder))]
   public class testDto
   {
       public string A { get; set; }
       public int B { get; set; }
   }
   ```