# FromForm fields are all null application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0

I am trying to mimic a live webapi for some testing I need to accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded api and read the form fields but the [FromForm] object fields are all null this is the request I am trying to accept in powershell script:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://localhost:7172/index.cgi" `
-Method "POST" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"  
} `
-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" `
-Body "log_btn=log_btn&usrName=admin&enPwd=TlSqAz7AoXLnC9yTB%2BlbwMYxYAjgUsfSJVzRyZagQE%2BPzl3pk0MAloTpWXaQBC1hnP%2F5t9Y0ZUlHPHLFAIr%2BvMY2LU1aMqpaWWUfMSDWEoN1eLeiqREGZoNhF7e1rDBcH552Ux7hLGK2vdFerUhntADs03Pc4JmZWs4MFgc1pYXMwdwpEXDpZs%2BSWniorD0r5WToCcAM04BinJtvtTJdk4W2XMcXQuyWPExYQTjqOtzREFwhA1kkheinB5ojduUt1sc5k38Ud4vwROYV7IqfttFGg6BswK3uD%2FVsOr7Nxa3O9GaIU7l%2F%2Fd6YKnl0nOo6afTw8Ybajc1axzP5LDt%2Frdsn7tfKTMH1zbrG8hWQi3QOrPFBZhCTQpkRdbjwp5i8s4bwqaR%2FWxuv%2Fc%2BEklMVKnn2S9JQb%2B9wz2EgoyJt5FkzF%2FzLgqdWE6xNU1h9%2B3%2FRiI%2BSoUnppg%2F7PIVtfueckIrK7Rt18X3IyIyVY0pf84yhE1WwU5ah9jSVQ8cVF2Cm0ccACLk8wZVBzjxwVRjUkx%2FWD5uNa8w5m342vxyfmJrfF4QG7KgloSzXd9stOvaV2lmzRBrCwwdVi2ybtpQ%2F12i5hdcv7wMR3WIz%2BJCekHMsYYXk1rH5M%2BosGyoQBl%2FRqKoPbxpAtFsm0x2R17dwE2u6q4RGYzF9318NzaFkg%2BI%3D&randomNum=RepyOPNzyxpn4QehUt1nRocrytpsIOQr&cbRem=true" `
-SkipCertificateCheck
```

My Endpoint fires correctly I Created a class "LoginForm" to populate the form fields but every field is null

```
 [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {       
     
        [Route("index.cgi")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromForm] LoginForm playerPackage)
        {                                   

            return Ok();
        }



    }
    public class LoginForm
    {
        public string log_btn;
        public string usrName;
        public string enPwd;
        public string randomNum;
        public string cbRem;
    }
```

Here is the Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    return next();
});
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: `playerPackage` looks familiar... hmmm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041127/accept-x-www-form-urlencoded-in-web-api-net-core

Comment: yes it is, when googling the problem to this came up. I tried the accepted answer and top rated answers with no success.

Comment: Please post your `Configure()` method (not `ConfigureServices()`, but the ASP.NET Pipeline/middleware config method).

Comment: added the program.cs \

Comment: What if you add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore` in your `ConfigureServices` method, and `UseMvc()` in your pipeline? (I forget _where_ exactly `UseMvc()` should go relative to the other methods though).